# When parsing RSS feed, wrong date is displayed

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$RSSFEEDS = array(
    0 => "http://samnabi.posterous.com/rss.xml",
);
function FormatRow($date, $title, $link, $description) {
return <<<HTML
<p class="blogdate">$date</p><h2 class="blogtitle">$title</h2>
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
$description
HTML;
}
ob_start();
if (!isset($feedid)) $feedid = 0;
$rss_url = $RSSFEEDS[$feedid];
$rss_feed = file_get_contents($rss_url);
$rss_feed = str_replace("<![CDATA[", "", $rss_feed);
$rss_feed = str_replace("]]>", "", $rss_feed);
$rss_feed = str_replace("\n", "", $rss_feed);
$rss_feed = preg_replace('#<image>(.*?)</image>#', '', $rss_feed, 1 );
preg_match_all('#<pubDate>(.*?)</pubDate>#', $rss_feed, $date, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
preg_match_all('#<title>(.*?)</title>#', $rss_feed, $title, PREG_SET_ORDER);  
preg_match_all('#<link>(.*?)</link>#', $rss_feed, $link, PREG_SET_ORDER);
preg_match_all('#<description>(.*?)</description>#', $rss_feed, $description, PREG_SET_ORDER);
if(count($title) <= 1) {
    echo "No new blog posts. Check back soon!";
}
else {
    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 3; $counter++ ) {
        if(!empty($title[$counter][1])) {
            $title[$counter][1] = str_replace("&", "&", $title[$counter][1]);
            $title[$counter][1] = str_replace("&apos;", "'", $title[$counter][1]);          
            $row = FormatRow($date[$counter][1],$title[$counter][1],$link[$counter][1],$description[$counter][1]);
            echo $row;
        }
    }
} 
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

When this script is run, the first item displays the second item's **pubDate**. The second item displays the third item's **pubDate**, and so on. So the dates that are shown are not the dates that you see in the original XML file. How do I fix this?

Bonus question: how do I strip characters off the beginning and end of the **pubDate** tag, so that I end up with "15 May 2010" instead of "Sat, 15 May 2010 03:28:00 -0700" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've said it [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129937/how-do-i-take-an-rss-feed-from-wordpress-com-and-add-the-newest-post-of-the-feed), so I'll say it again: Use [Magpie RSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) to parse your RSS feeds. It takes care of all this stuff for you, and will be much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Magpie RSS works great. Here's the code I used to replace what was in my original question:

```
<?php

define('MAGPIE_INPUT_ENCODING', 'UTF-8');
define('MAGPIE_OUTPUT_ENCODING', 'UTF-8');

//Tell it to use the fetch script to grab the RSS feed
require_once('magpie/rss_fetch.inc');

//Now it knows how to fetch RSS, tell it which one to fetch
$rss = fetch_rss('http://samnabi.posterous.com/rss.xml');

//In this case, we only want to display the first 3 items
$items = array_slice($rss->items,0,3);

//Now we tell Magpie how to format our output
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $title = $item['title'];
    $date = date('d M Y', strtotime($item['pubdate']));
    $link = $item['link'];
    $description = $item['description'];       

    //And now we want to put it all together.
    echo "<p>$date</p><h2>$title</h2><p>$description</p>";
}

?>
```